# How can I read/write from/to files with MSSQL 2000?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In MySQL you can quite simply read a file with `SELECT load_file('foo.txt')` and write to a file with `SELECT 'text' INTO DUMPFILE 'foo.txt'`.

I am looking for a way to do this in MSSQL 2000 without using any external tools, just with queries or stored procedures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For input, you can use the text file ODBC driver:

```
select * from OpenRowset('MSDASQL',
'Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt;
*.csv)};DefaultDir=c:\;','select * from [FileName.csv]')
```

Assuming the output file already exists, you can use Jet to write to it:

```
INSERT INTO
OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
'Text;Database=C:\;HDR=Yes;', 'SELECT
* FROM filename.csv')   SELECT 1234,5678
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways you can do this.

using xp_cmdshell:

```
declare @writetofile varchar(1000)
select @writetofile = 'osql -U -P -S -Q"select * from yourtable" -o"c:\foo.txt"'

exec master..xp_cmdshell @writetofile
```

Or you can use bcp from the command line to read/write to files, which is usually quicker to do bulk inserts/selects

Alternatively, you can also use sp_OACreate, but you probably don't want to go this route since it's not exactly what databases are meant to do. :)

Comment: I dont have xp_cmdshell, and as said I dont want external tools like bcp. Could you please explain the sp_OACreate further?

Comment: The file operations in MySQL aren't particularly standard and there is no real equivalent; the options posted here by volatilsis are really your only options on SQL Server.

Comment: Well, thanks then, upvote given to both, although none of the methods really work for my case :/

Comment: The main issue you're dealing with in sql server are permissions to the file system.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use BULK INSERT to read files.